# При переносе на wp перестала работать карусель

Tags: javascript

Уже целый день сижу немогу понять почему не работает карусель
[вот ссылка](http://kinyokush.tmweb.ru/good-enough/)

Менял местами скрипты, переносил вверх, копался в коде, но не понял
Это с тильды брал, на самой тильде все прекрасно работает 
[вот от тильды](http://project68329.tilda.ws/good)

```
(function( $ ){
 function t_initZoom(){
   if ( $('[data-zoomable="yes"]').length ) {    
     $('[data-zoomable="yes"]').addClass("t-zoomable");
     $("body").append('<div class="t-zoomer__wrapper">\
       <div class="t-zoomer__container">\
       </div>\
       <div class="t-zoomer__bg"></div>\
       <div class="t-zoomer__close">\
         <div class="t-zoomer__close-line t-zoomer__close-line-first"></div>\
         <div class="t-zoomer__close-line t-zoomer__close-line-second"></div>\
       </div>\
     </div>');
     t_showZoom();
     $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show");
         $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show_fixed");
       }
     });
     $('.t-zoomer__close, .t-zoomer__bg').click(function(e){  
       $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show");
       $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show_fixed");
     });
   }
 } 

 function t_showZoom(){
   $('.t-zoomable').click(function(e){
     $("body").addClass("t-zoomer__show");
     $(".t-zoomer__container").html('<div id="t-carousel__zoomed" class="t-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">\
       <div class="t-carousel__slides t-carousel__zoomer__slides">\
         <div class="t-carousel__inner t-carousel__zoomer__inner">\
         </div>\
         <a class="left t-carousel__control t-carousel__zoomer__control" href="#t-carousel__zoomed" data-slide="prev">\
           <div class="t-carousel__arrow__wrapper t-carousel__arrow__wrapper_left">\
             <div class="t-carousel__arrow t-carousel__arrow_left t-carousel__arrow_small"></div>\
           </div>\
         </a>\
         <a class="right t-carousel__control t-carousel__zoomer__control" href="#t-carousel__zoomed" data-slide="next">\
           <div class="t-carousel__arrow__wrapper t-carousel__arrow__wrapper_right">\
             <div class="t-carousel__arrow t-carousel__arrow_right t-carousel__arrow_small"></div>\
           </div>\
         </a>\
       </div>\
     </div>');

     var id = $(this).closest(".r").attr("id");
     var images = $("#"+id+"").find(".t-zoomable");
     images.each(function () {
       var images_urls = $(this).attr('data-img-zoom-url').split(',');
       if($(this).is("img")) {
         var imgdescr = $(this).attr('alt');
       } else {
            if ($(this).is("div")) {
                var imgdescr = $(this).attr('title');
            }
       }
       images_urls.forEach(function() {
         if (typeof imgdescr !== typeof undefined && imgdescr !== false) {
           $(".t-carousel__zoomer__inner").append("<div class=\"t-carousel__item t-carousel__zoomer__item item\"><div class=\"t-carousel__zoomer__wrapper\"><img class=\"t-carousel__zoomer__img\" src=\""+images_urls+"\"></div><div class=\"t-zoomer__comments\"><div class=\"t-zoomer__descr t-descr t-descr_xxs\">"+imgdescr+"</div></div></div>");            
         } else {
           $(".t-carousel__zoomer__inner").append("<div class=\"t-carousel__item t-carousel__zoomer__item item\"><div class=\"t-carousel__zoomer__wrapper\"><img class=\"t-carousel__zoomer__img\" src=\""+images_urls+"\"></div><div class=\"t-zoomer__comments\"></div></div>");
         }
       });
     });

     var image_descr = $(".t-carousel__zoomer__item");
     image_descr.each(function () {
       $(this).css("display", "block");
       var height = $(this).find(".t-zoomer__comments").height();
       $(this).css("display", "");
       var image_active = $(this).find(".t-carousel__zoomer__wrapper");
       image_active.css("bottom", height);
     });

     var target_url = $(this).attr("data-img-zoom-url"),
       target_img = $(".t-carousel__zoomer__img[src=\""+target_url+"\"]"),
       target = target_img.closest(".t-carousel__zoomer__item");
       target.addClass("active");

     var slides_count = $(".t-carousel__zoomer__item").size();
     if (slides_count > 1) {
        $('body').addClass("t-zoomer__show_fixed"); 
     } else {
        $(".t-carousel__zoomer__control").css("display", "none");
     }


     $('.t-carousel__zoomer__img').click(function(e){  
       $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show");
       $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show_fixed");
     });

     var lastScrollTop = 0;
     $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){     
         $('body').removeClass("t-zoomer__show");
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
     });
   });
 } 

 $(document).ready(function(){
   t_initZoom();
 });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так в консоли же ответ

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

В ворпрессе $ не работает, нужно либо jQuery писать, либо оборачивать

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(бла).find(бла)...
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вроде же обернут? или я неправильно вас понял, пример кода засунул

Comment: Доллар замените на jQuery

Comment: все доллары чтоли? я так сделал, но толку было 0

Comment: Добавил скриншот с номерами строк